# Is it possible to search all markers in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe

If I have added markers to multiple clips, how do I search for those markers using the text within the markers, if they're not already in a sequence?

For example: I have a clip that is playing, I hit M to mark.  I type "good" into the marker description.  I now want to find that marker globally in my whole project.  The clip isn't in a sequence yet.  Can I?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently a feature, but one work around is to throw all your sequences (nested) into one sequence and then in the Markers window right click the tab menu and select "Show all clip markers in sequence".

This will give you one big searchable list of markers in all the sequences in your big sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Project` panel search box to find your specific markers, and even save your search as a Search Bin by clicking the folder icon with the magnifying glass.

[image]

You can then search within each matching clip for the specific marker by first selecting that clip in the Project panel, then using the search in the Markers panel which you can open by going to `Windows > Markers`

[image]
[image]

You can find additional information about searching your project in [Adobe's help documentation on finding assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/finding-assets.html).

Comment: My question is about how to search all markers in a project at once.

Comment: I believe that only searches the markers in the currently active sequence (but I could be wrong - hence the question!)

Comment: You know there's a metadata checkbox for "good," right?  I completely understand that it might not address your needs, and that maybe you need to associate a time with a keyword, or maybe you're just using the word "good" as an example, but on the off chance that you're actually using markers to mark things good...  you could just use the checkbox and then sort by the "good" column.

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, that does only search the markers in the active sequence, but you can use the general search, or search bin, to find the clips with the markers you're looking for first. It's a little inconvenient to have to do a search in the Project panel, then a search in the Markers panel, but I'm not sure if there are other options. I'll update the answer too.

Comment: if I add all clips to one enormous sequence, then use that to search my markers, is that a daft idea?